# iCheck undo check

Tags: jquery, icheck

I want to do some validation when checkbox is checked and uncheck it if validation fails.

Right now, the checked property is false but the checkbox remains checked.

Mycode:

```
$("#Lve_InclWE").on('ifChecked', function(event){
    some_function();
    if(!some_validation())
        $('#Lve_InclWE').iCheck('uncheck');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="icheckbox_flat-green checked" style="position: relative;">
<input type="checkbox" class="icheck" id="Lve_InclWE" name="Lve_InclWE" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
```

update1: Even if I do this, the problem remains:

```
$("#Lve_InclWE").removeProp("checked"); 
//$("#Lve_InclWE").prop("checked",false);
$("#Lve_InclWE").iCheck('update');
```

update2: Tried removing checked class at parent div but the same. Is it because I execute within the check event?

```
$('#Lve_InclWE').closest("div").removeClass("checked");
```

**update3:** I added an alert at the end of the "ifChecked" event and noticed that the checkbox actually been unchecked, but it returns to checked state after the event ends. Which means I cannot perform the undo check(uncheck) within the triggered event, any method you can think of?

Comment: Can you add a `jsfiddle` DEMO?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao never used jsFiddle before. Just tried but failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution and possible the ONLY solution is to uncheck the checkbox AFTER event ended, using setTimeOut(fn,0)

```
$("#Lve_InclWE").on('ifChecked', function(event){
    if(!validation()){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#Lve_InclWE').iCheck('uncheck');
        },0);
    }
});
```

The reason is because the checkbox always set to **checked** state after the triggered event.

If you have another solution feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to destroy & recreate the iCheck.

```
$("#Lve_InclWE").on('ifChecked', function(event){
    some_function();
    if(!some_validation()){  
        $('#Lve_InclWE').iCheck('destroy');
        $('#Lve_InclWE').prop('checked', true);
        /*
            Now reinitialize iCheck for #Lve_InclWE
        */
    }       
});
```